# Saltstack docker.login returns APIError: 500 Server Error?

Tags: python-2.7, docker, salt-stack, dockerpy

I was created a private repository at https://hub.docker.com and docker login working fine. I am trying to make it via saltstack and login using this [link](http://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/modules/all/salt.modules.dockerio.html#salt.modules.dockerio.login).

```
salt '*' docker.login <url> <username> <password> <email>
salt '*' docker.login 'https://registry.hub.docker.com/v1/' 'username' 'password' 'XxXX.xxxx@xxxx.XXX'
```

I was getting this error

```
 The minion function caused an exception: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/salt/minion.py", line 797, in _thread_return
    return_data = func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/salt/modules/dockerio.py", line 1167, in login
    return client.login(url, username, password, email)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/docker/client.py", line 615, in login
    return self._result(response, json=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/docker/client.py", line 86, in _result
    self._raise_for_status(response)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/docker/client.py", line 82, in _raise_for_status
    raise errors.APIError(e, response, explanation=explanation)
APIError: 500 Server Error: Internal Server Error ("</html>")
```

I think the repository url was wrong. The URL must end with /v1/ as per the [issue](https://github.com/docker/docker-py/issues/241)
What is "registry url to authenticate to" for my repository?

Comment: Did you try `https://index.docker.io/v1/` for the URL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was working with this format. (Without any URL).

```
salt '*' cmd.run "docker login -u username -p password -e email@xxxxx.xxx"
```

(or)

```
 salt '*' docker.login 'username' 'password' 'email@xxxxx.xxx'
```